# when creating elasticsearch java plugin and run elasticsearch it throws Initialization Failed ... - VerifyError

Tags: java, maven, plugins, elasticsearch-plugin

I have cloned http url to practice elasticsearch java plugin.
https://github.com/iterativ/elasticsearch-listindices.git
but at last when i have tried  below command
 **bin/elasticsearch** then found  error-

*(/dev/sda5)]], net usable_space [40.6gb], net total_space [45.7gb], types [ext4]
{1.7.1}: Initialization Failed ...
- VerifyError[class ch.iterativ.es.plugin.listindices.rest.IndicesRestHandler overrides final method handleRequest.(Lorg/elasticsearch/rest/RestRequest;Lorg/elasticsearch/rest/RestChannel;)V]*

Comment: approx how much size of directory/branch are you going for initialize?

Comment: how much size ,not understand ? Git project cloned succesfully but there is error when i have executed elasticsearch after completing all process.

Comment: opps i don't see the cloned successfully!

Comment: may be you need to try uninstall and once again try for clone